# Changing resolution of Session0\Default desktop?

Tags: windows-7, resolution, services

As part of a script running from a service, I want to automate some GUI tests. The application I'm testing requires the screen size to be full HD (1920x1080) or higher, but the size of the desktop while running **from the service** is reported to be 1280x1024. Is there a way to change this, either from the script or as a registry setting?

I am running this on Windows7 btw. Any tips would be appreciated.

All of this is running on a PC that has no monitor/screen attached.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the resolution higher if you uncheck 'hide resolution that monitor can't display' and you might see 1400 times 1050, 1600 times 1200, 1832 times 1392 or what you want because your computer is a 4:3, 2048 times 1536 resolution, which is just needed to work it. But I just don't know if it'll burn up your monitor, but use that as your own risk. Maybe, in some advanced computers, have some 'emergency pixels' so you can use them to set higher resolution if needed.

Comment: They keep those emergency pixels in a spare bit bucket.  When they're needed, little elves stick them on the plastic bezel around the screen to give you extra viewing area.

Comment: This describe how to change the resolution of a login-desktop with a monitor attached, not the session0 desktop that services run on!

Comment: Yah. also those emergency pixels also replace dead pixels.

Comment: I think there was a terrible film recently involving pixels causing an emergency...